# How can I get gdbserver to run the target program on start?

Tags: gdb, remote-debugging, gdbserver

Just like it says above.  The program needs to be invoked in sequence with others, by a script and I'd like to have it run automatically so that it is as true to the actual running conditions as possible.

***Edit***

I wasn't able to find an answer to this, but just in case someone comes looking here's how I worked around it, since I had access to gdb and screen on the target.

```
screen -d -m gdb -x debugstart
```

where debugstart is a simple script containing:

```
file program
r
```

this will launch a screen session and start gdb in it which starts running your program and then detatch from that screen session so you can just  *screen -r* when you need to look at the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You don't explain why you want GDB to trace your program, and I guess it is to catch errors at run time (e.g., signals of fatal errors), which is a good practice in case of hardly reproductible errors.

So one way is to run `gdbserver` using the option `--multi`. You'll then be able to remotely run your program and then to stop its execution pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> (or command `interrupt`).

Running gdbserver

```
$ gdbserver --multi <server address>
```

GDB script:

```
target extended-remote <server address>
remote put <your program>
set remote exec-file <your program>
# you could pre-set breakpoints, or whatever
run
# ctrl-c to interrupt the execution of the started process
```

Otherwise, you could simply run your program and then remotely attach to it with `gdbserver --attach` when required.

Comment: As you guessed I was trying to catch a fatal error. However, that error only ever seemed to occur if it was invoked during system startup, so there was no way to run gdbserver --attach before it would have crashed. I'm not sure that gdbserver was the right approach in the first place anyway.

Comment: the correct command is `remote put <yourHostProgram> <yourTargetProgram>`